# how do you pull in the html from a URL?

Tags: c#, .net

I have one site that is displaying html content that needs to be displayed on another site (first site is front end to content management system).

So site1 page = http://site1/pagecontent

and on site 2 (http://site2/pagecontent) I need to be able to display the contents shown on site 1 page.

I am using .Net C# (MVC), and do not want to just use an iframe.

Is there a way to suck in the html into a string variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the WebClient class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

```
WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
string s = wClient.DownloadString(site2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  See the [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class, specificially, the [`DownloadString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx) method.